# Customizer API and pages

Tags: customization

I try to develop customizer API in my Theme but I have a litle problem. When I'm in customizer in left side I have some section (My Section) and there is color picker to change background color. After change color the bg-color is changed but this works only on home page. After when I go to different page the bg-color isn't changed and when I change color after page refresh I always redirected to home page. There is the way to customize all defined pages?

I use https://github.com/aristath/kirki/ framework to integrate with customizer API. This is my settings:

```
/**
 * The configuration options for the Shoestrap Customizer
 */
function silverwp_customizer_config() {

    $args = array(

        // Change the logo image. (URL)
        // If omitted, the default theme info will be displayed.
        // A good size for the logo is 250x50.
        'logo_image'   => SILVERWP_THEME_URL . '/lib/SilverWp/libs/kirki/assets/img/logo.png',

        // The color of active menu items, help bullets etc.
        'color_active' => '#1abc9c',

        // Color used for secondary elements and desable/inactive controls
        'color_light'  => '#8cddcd',

        // Color used for button-set controls and other elements
        'color_select' => '#34495e',

        // Color used on slider controls and image selects
        'color_accent' => '#FF5740',

        // The generic background color.
        // You should choose a dark color here as we're using white for the text color.
        'color_back'   => '#222',

        // If Kirki is embedded in your theme, then you can use this line to specify its location.
        // This will be used to properly enqueue the necessary stylesheets and scripts.
        // If you are using kirki as a plugin then please delete this line.
        'url_path'     => SILVERWP_THEME_URL . '/lib/SilverWp/libs/kirki/',

        // If you want to take advantage of the backround control's 'output',
        // then you'll have to specify the ID of your stylesheet here.
        // The "ID" of your stylesheet is its "handle" on the wp_enqueue_style() function.
        // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style
        'stylesheet_id' => 'project_style',

    );
    return $args;

}
add_filter( 'kirki/config', 'silverwp_customizer_config' );

/**
 * Create the section
 */
function my_custom_section( $wp_customize ) {

    // Create the "My Section" section
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'my_section', array(
        'title'    => __( 'My Section', 'translation_domain' ),
        'priority' => 12
    ) );

}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'my_custom_section' );

/**
 * Create the setting
 */
function my_custom_setting( $controls ) {

    $controls[] = array(
        'type'     => 'color',
        'setting'  => 'bg-color',
        'label'    => __( 'My Setting', 'textdomain' ),
        'section'  => 'my_section',
        'default'  => '#1abc9c',
        'priority' => 1,
    );
    return $controls;
}
add_filter( 'kirki/controls', 'my_custom_setting' );
```

I don't want to use inline css after save so I display inline styles only in customizer page

```
function test() {
    global $kirki, $wp_customize;
    if (isset($wp_customize)) {
        $kirki_config = $kirki->get_config();

        $bg_color = get_theme_mod('bg-color', '#000000');
        $css = 'body {background-color:'.$bg_color.';}';
        wp_add_inline_style( $kirki_config['stylesheet_id'], $css );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test', 150 );
```

Regards

Comment: please update your question to include the relevant code you're using

Comment: OK. Here you are.